# why use present perfect in" Has Russia economy worked well, why or why not" here

Tags: tense

Currently i am writing on essay on" has Russia economy worked well? Why or why not" I don't understand what's the implication of present perfect here. Does the question want me to discuss the economy fared between further past to the present time? Or only talk about the past few years. I am thinking to start from the collapse of the Soviet to the presen

Comment: Do you understand that the title is actually not very good English to begin with?

Comment: Anything that goes up to the present moment would be a candidate for the present perfect.  The length of the time period is not relevant.  We could ask "**Has** planet earth **been** getting closer to the sun  over the past 4 billion years?"

Comment: Has *the* Russian economy... is required for good English.

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect has several uses, one of which is to indicate a continuous or repeated action up to the present moment.  For example:

> His family **has served** the royal family for generations.

This implies a continuous, unbroken chain of service which *has continued* until the present day.  In a similar way, "Has the economy worked?" is asking whether Russia's economic policies have been continuously *effective*, or at least, whether their continuous effects have been positive.

In this way it's actually an open-ended question.  You may focus on any period you wish, as long as you eventually relate it to the present.  For example, you can talk about how the collapse of the Soviet union negatively affected the economy at that time, but then explain how it has since rebounded (and why).  Or you could go further back and talk about the Tsar rule and the Russian Revolution, if you think that's more relevant to the current economic situation.

In the end, there is really no "correct" answer to this.  The Russian economy might be doing well today, but have problems tomorrow.  Your opinion only presents a "snapshot" of the current moment.